# Python typing a function that converts all values in a container recursively

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy, typing

I am dealing with an object that comes from a database that is a subclass of `dict`, but it is not defined in a way where it can take any type arguments. In my below sample I have named this type `SpecialDict`, for the purposes of what I am doing I just want to convert it to a standard `dict`.

Now, I am creating a function that will convert an instance of this `SpecialDict` to a standard `dict` - however, this `SpecialDict` (and the subsequent `dict`) can be arbitrarily nested but has certain constraints:

1. Keys are always `str`
2. It can contain other instances of `SpecialDict`
3. It can contain `list`
4. These container can in the end contain `int` and `str`

The real example is set up in this same way, but with more allowed atomic types than just `int` and `str`, but that should not affect the question.

Given the above, a simple recursive implementation of the above described function would be:

```
SUPPORTED_CONTAINER_TYPES = (dict, list)
SUPPORTED_ATOMIC_TYPES = (str, int)


class SpecialDict(dict):
    pass


def converter(container):
    if isinstance(container, dict):
        dict_ = {}
        for key, value in container.items():
            if isinstance(value, SUPPORTED_CONTAINER_TYPES):
                dict_[key] = converter(container=value)
            elif isinstance(value, SUPPORTED_ATOMIC_TYPES):
                dict_[key] = value
            else:
                raise TypeError(f"{type(value)} is not supported.")

        return dict_

    if isinstance(container, list):
        datastore_list = []
        for item in container:
            if isinstance(item, SUPPORTED_CONTAINER_TYPES):
                datastore_list.append(converter(container=item))
            elif isinstance(item, SUPPORTED_ATOMIC_TYPES):
                datastore_list.append(item)
            else:
                raise TypeError(f"{type(item)} is not supported.")

        return datastore_list

    raise TypeError(f"{type(container)} is not supported.")
```

Essentially, we go through the `SpecialDict` recursively and fill in a new `dict`. The issue is that I can't get this typed properly.

The function can take as input either a `list`, `dict` or `SpecialDict` (which also is a `dict` subclass though) and returns either `list` or `dict`.

However, since these can all arbitrarily contain themselves or the other container types, I would try to define the types recursively along these lines:

```
from typing import Union

SUPPORTED_CONTAINER_TYPES = (dict, list)
SUPPORTED_ATOMIC_TYPES = (str, int)


class SpecialDict(dict):
    pass


MyList = list[Union[str, int, "MyList", "MyDict", SpecialDict]]
MyDict = dict[str, Union[str, int, MyList, "MyDict", SpecialDict]]

MyListWithoutSpecialDict = list[Union[str, int, "MyList", "MyDict"]]
MyDictWithoutSpecialDict = dict[str, Union[str, int, MyList, "MyDict"]]


def converter(container: MyList | MyDict) -> MyListWithoutSpecialDict | MyDictWithoutSpecialDict:
    if isinstance(container, dict):
        dict_ = {}
        for key, value in container.items():
            if isinstance(value, SUPPORTED_CONTAINER_TYPES):
                dict_[key] = converter(container=value)
            elif isinstance(value, SUPPORTED_ATOMIC_TYPES):
                dict_[key] = value
            else:
                raise TypeError(f"{type(value)} is not supported.")

        return dict_

    if isinstance(container, list):
        datastore_list = []
        for item in container:
            if isinstance(item, SUPPORTED_CONTAINER_TYPES):
                datastore_list.append(converter(container=item))
            elif isinstance(item, SUPPORTED_ATOMIC_TYPES):
                datastore_list.append(item)
            else:
                raise TypeError(f"{type(item)} is not supported.")

        return datastore_list

    raise TypeError(f"{type(container)} is not supported.")
```

But this gives a number of mypy errors and also does not really seem to capture what I am trying to do. It might help to break the function up a bit into another one that does some of the type coercion, but at the end of the day I will always be left with the type hints for this outer most function that I am not sure how to resolve.

Any advice?

Comment: As a side note, you might consider using a type alias for `Union[str, int, MyList, "MyDict"]` to avoid repeating it in several places. You can also avoid the mixed quoting of types if you use `from __future__ import annotations`. It's also interesting that you mix `Union` and `|` for expressing union types. Any reason not to stick to `|`?

Comment: just out of curiosity can you `real_dict = json.loads(json.dumps(special_dict))`?

Comment: `converter` should really be two separate functions. Part of your problem is trying to merge two functions with different types into one.

Comment: @Brian61354270 yeah so in my original code I have it aliased, did not want to introduce too many variables in the example for simplcity, but was maybe causing more confusion than helping. As for the pipe vs union thing, I actually did not know that you could use pipe for types defined as string when when importing from future, thanks for the pointer!

Comment: @JonSG unfortunately not, it can contain some types which are not JSON serializable

Comment: @chepner yeah I agree, but doesnt the problem stand for the outer-most function still if I remove the part with list?

Comment: If there was a way to serialize such cases, would that work as a solution for you?  Can you give an example of such a data point (maybe say a Decimal type?)

Comment: @JonSG for example bytes, datetime.datetime and to be very specific this is relating to datastore in google cloud platform, so there is a supported internal type defined in google.cloud.datastore.helpers called GeoPoint that must also be supported

Answer (score 2):

What you want is a type-level mapping of

- `MyList -> MyListWithoutSpecialDict`
- `MyDict -> MyDictWithoutSpecialDict`

Then you could define something like

```
# N.B. MyList and MyDict need to be real types, not type hints
T = TypeVar('T', MyList, MyDict)

def converter(container: T) -> TF[T]:
    ...
```

where `TF` provides the mapping.

I don't think Python's type hints supports such a concept yet.

---

Note that your type hints on `converter` implicitly define a type

```
Callable[[Union[MyList, MyDict]], 
         Union[MyListWithoutSpecialDict, MyDictWithoutSpecialDict]]
```

which is not the same as the type you want, namely

```
Union[
    Callable[[MyList], MyListWithoutSpecialDict],
    Callable[[MyDict], MyDictWithoutSpecialDict]
]
```

If the syntax allowed it, you could write something like

```
converter: Union[Callable[...], Callable[...]]  # per above
def converter(container):
    ...
```

The hypothetical type mapping `TF` is the piece that lets you work within Python's syntax to define the equivalent type

```
Callable[[T], TF[T]]
```

Comment: hmm since this is a hypothetical, does this mean that I am left with doing something not quite right and adding type ignores where mypy would complain? or is there a solution that is perhaps not covering all bases, but is at least correct?

Comment: I made this a community wiki in the hopes that someone else knows how to define `TF`. I think there's a way by defining a custom type that overloads `__class_getitem__`, but I don't have anything working yet.

Comment: My definition of the constrained variable `T` is also wrong at the moment, as it needs types, not type aliases, for the constraints.

Comment: re: "if the syntax allowed it", isn't that more or less exactly what [`typing.overload`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload) is for?

Comment: I suppose it is :) But I don't really like it, as it would usually be much cleaner to just specify a single `Callable` hint for a function rather than having to spread it across multiple dummy definitions in the form of function annotations.

Comment: ah interesting, if no one chimes in with a more succinct solution I guess the typing.overload should make it possible, although I agree it not the nicest thing to look at